# Why does the latest version of Titanium Studio need android platform 2.3.* version

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile, android-sdk-tools, hybrid-mobile-app

I installed the latest version of Titanium Studio which is `Titanium Studio, build: 3.1.*` and it requires Android SDK. In the Android Configuration Details of Titanium Studio, Under - Items Required, it says: **Titanium requires Android platform 2.3.***

I'm kind of new to this subject and I don't understand why it needs a older version of android SDK. Why doesn't it require the latest version? Is there a specific reason for this?

[image]

Comment: Good question, I think since Titanium has been in the market since 2008 it needs some previous Android SDK to work, but i don't know either